# Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView

Tags: java, android, youtubeplayer

I am trying to play videos from Youtube inside ListAdapter but i got this Error only with api <= 23 , does that mean only api > 23 are supported with youtubeplayer ? 
is there another way to play Youtube videos in android applications ? 
this is my code and xml files 
i have tried to extend YoutubeBaseActivity but did not solve the problem

```
private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<String> entries;
    private final List<View> entryViews;
    private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;
    private boolean labelsVisible;
    public PageAdapter(Context context, List<String > entries) {
      this.entries = entries;
      entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
      thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();
      labelsVisible = true;
    }

    public void releaseLoaders() {
      for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
        loader.release();
      }
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
      labelsVisible = visible;
      for (View view : entryViews) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
      return entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = convertView;
      String entry = entries.get(position);

      // There are three cases here
      if (view == null) {
        // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setTag(entry);
        thumbnail.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);
      } else {
        YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
        if (loader == null) {
          // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
          //    current videoId in the tag.
          thumbnail.setTag(entry);
        } else {
          // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
          //    on the loader.
          thumbnail.setImageResource(R.mipmap.appicon);
          loader.setVideo(entry);
        }
      }
      TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
      label.setText(entry);
      label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
      return view;
    }

    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

      @Override
      public void onInitializationSuccess(
              YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
        loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
        String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
        loader.setVideo(videoId);
      }

      @Override
      public void onInitializationFailure(
              YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, ErrorReason errorReason) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.animationstart);
      }
    }

  }
```

and this is the xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"


    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
      android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/no_thumbnail" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_weight="0"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
```

Comment: Make sure your activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity.

Comment: I tried , i mention that in my post , 
but does not work

Comment: Have you added dependency for YouTube API or a library project?